# How the operator 'is' works? (identity operator) in python

Tags: python, numpy, identity

I thought 'is' operator would return True if the two variables are pointing the same object. (not just value)
In the example below,

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = a[1:3]
b[0] = 11
```

then a[1] value will be changed to 11.
And b array will be pointing to the a[1:3].

So I thought 'b[0] is a[1]' would return True. (b[0] and  a[1] are referencing the same object)
But that line returned False.

Could you help me to understand why the result is False?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language is this? Please update the tags.

Comment: Youi wasted five tags that weren't needed, and left off the one that actually was, which is the language you're using. Please [edit] your post, remove all 5 tags you have now, and add just the one for that language.

Comment: They're not the same object. They're two different objects referencing different parts of the same underlying memory (underlying memory that isn't a Python level object itself, so it can never be identity tested), but the *objects themselves* are different (they *have* to be; the same object *obviously* can't refer to the whole array *and* just elements 1 and 2 *at the same time*).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: The `is` test was on `b[0]` and `a[1]`, not `b` and `a`.

Comment: It will help if you read intro docs that explain how numpy stores and accesses arrays.  It's not the same as lists.